# gene inversion and DNA directionality

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics, mutations

The directionality of the DNA goes from the 3-prime end to the 5-prime end.

Thus, the inversion of a gene would connect a 5-prime to a 5-prime. How could that be?

Maybe inverting a gene also switches between the two strands of the DNA?
Thus, if one stand goes from 5 to 3, and the other goes from 3 to 5,
Inversion would make the first go from 3 to 5, and the other from 5 to 3,
And then each strand would be able to connect to the other?

Does inversion both changes direction, and switches stands?
If not, then how is gene inversion possible?

Thanks!

edit:
My main question arises from the contradiction between:

1) The DNA has a direction (3-prime to 5-prime).

2) inversion inverts the direction.

Thus, my question is: How can an inversion mutation happen?
How can a piece of the DNA, after being inverted (i.e., it is now in the wrong direction), connect back to the DNA?

Comment: Hello and welcome at Biology SE! can you please clarify your question? It might be only me but it's hard for me to figure out what do you mean by inversion and 'different strands go from'. You also have multiple questions can you please narrow it down

Comment: Thank you!
I updated my question to narrow it down to the main thing that bothers me.

Comment: Draw yourself a sample gene of say 10 base pairs marking 5’ and 3’ ends of the strands. Invert it — voila! Hint — I wrote base pairs and strands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, chromosomal DNA has two strands, with each strand running in opposite 5' <-> 3' directions.  When a chromosomal segment is inverted, both the 5'->3' sequence and its complementary 3'->5' sequence from the other strand are inverted together.  When reattached to the two strands it came from, the segment will have effectively switched its orientation on both strands by switching strands.  This happens exactly because a 5' end must mate with a 3' end.  This diagram should help make this clear (although it shows a duplication with inversion instead of an inversion in place):

[image: Inverted Repeat]

*Source: [Wikipedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Inverted-Repeat.gif)*

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!